# Cohomology of a punctured torus using Mayer Vietoris

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, de-rham-cohomology

I have figured out how to use Mayer Vietoris to find cohomology of $T^2$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3242466/cohomology-of-t2-using-mayer-vietoris/3243615#3243615). For a punctured torus, following the hint, let $U$ = $T^2\setminus S^1_1$ and $V$ = $T^2\setminus S^1_2$ such the $S^1_1\cap S^1_2$ is the puncture point. Am I correct in saying $H^0(U)=H^0(V)=H^1(U)=H^1(V) = \mathbb{R}$, $H^2(U)=H^2(V)=0$? Also may I know what $U\cap V$ is diffeomorphic to so as to find $H^0(U\cap V)$ and $H^1(U\cap V)$? $U\cap V = T^2\setminus S_1^1\cup S_2^1$.

Comment: How about $U$ and $V$ each being the torus minus a circle, with the two circles meeting at your favourite point?

Comment: That would be perfect. Let me try to attempt cohomology and update the question.

Comment: [This question and answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3239775/90543) might help you.

Comment: The approach outlined in that question/answer is to apply Mayer-Vietoris to $T^2$ with the open sets being $U=T^2\setminus \{p\}$ and $V$ a small open neighborhood of $p$ homeomorphic to a disk.

Comment: @jgon Thanks! Let me try to find the cohomology with this.

Comment: @manifolded Either way will work, Lord Shark the Unknown's strategy is also good. Indeed, for this particular case, it might be the easiest strategy. The method I suggested is more general, but a little more work for this particular case.

Comment: @jgon true, but the sets looks simpler to find cohomologies for with your link. Would $U\cap V = S^1$ in that case?

Comment: @manifolded Yes, well, whichever way you'd like to go about it I guess.